# ResourceNotFoundException for resource in library gradle module during instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

During an instrumentation test, my app is throwing the following error. This error is not thrown in my non-test builds.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f030002
```

I have two gradle modules

```
:app (android-application) //applicationId: com.app
:library (android-library) //applicationId: com.library
//:app includes :library as a dependency
```

The resource in question is defined and thrown in the `:library` module.

While under instrumentation, my `:library` module calls:

- `context.getResources().getString(com.library.R.string.pref_key)` - this throws an exception

If I debug at a breakpoint during instrumentation and call:

- `context.getResources().getString(com.app.R.string.pref_key)` - this works! But this is code from my `:library` module, which doesn't have a depedendency on `:app`.

How can I fix this? Note - the error only occurs during instrumentation tests, not normal builds.

UPDATE: while under instrumentation, calling `getString(com.library.R.string.pref_key)` works when called from a class within the `:app` module, but throws the exception from a class within the `:library` module. Literally, calling the exact same method on the same instance of `Resources` behaves differently when called from `:app` vs `:library`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why, but adding resources path manually could be something to try,

```
android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['res1', 'res2']
    }
}
}
```

refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html) for more information

Comment: the resources are actually there. The call just fails when it's made from within the `:library` module. if the *exact* same call is made from within the `:app` module, it works.